# IIS Rewriting with Query String and Question Mark IIS 7

Tags: iis-7, url-rewriting, url-rewrite-module

I have read the threads and I still can't work it out, my problem I know, but wondering if could point me in the right direction.

I have setup a rule:

```
www.mydomain.com/productlist.asp?CategoryID=2
```

rewritten to

```
www.mydomain.com/homeware/cushions
```

.

```
            <rule name="cushions">
                <match url="^homeware/cushions" />
                <action type="Rewrite" url="productlist.asp?CategoryID=2" />
            </rule>
```

ok, now my problem is with pagination of the results, so the original domain when the user goes onto the next page would look like:

```
www.mydomain.com/productlist.asp?CategoryID=2&Page=2
```

This is where I'm having problems - I want this to become:

```
www.mydomain.com/homeware/cushions?page=2
```

and ongoing for how many pages
just can't get it to work - I understand I need to use query string but really struggling. Asking for expertise, thanks for any help

Answer (score 2):

To capture the Query String you need to use conditions for that since the match URL does not include it.
So you could do that with a rule like:

```
<rule name="cushions" stopProcessing="true">
<match url="^homeware/cushions$" />
<conditions>
    <add input="{QUERY_STRING}" pattern="page=(\d+)" />
</conditions>
<action type="Rewrite" url="productlist.asp?CategoryID=2&amp;page={C:1}" appendQueryString="false" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add appendQueryString="true" in action will automatically append query string.

```
<rewrite>
        <rules>
            <rule name="test">
                <match url="^homeware/cushions" />
                <action type="Rewrite" url="/test/test.cfm?category=5" appendQueryString="true" />
                <conditions>
                </conditions>
            </rule>
        </rules>
    </rewrite>
```

http://localhost:8081/homeware/cushions?page=2
You will receive page in URL variable with value 2.